# Print rows from output1 based on output2 values

Tags: python, pandas

df1

```
slot              Time     Location  User
56  2017-10-26 22:15:00     89        1
2   2017-10-27 00:30:00     54        1
20  2017-10-28 05:00:00     64        1
24  2017-10-29 06:00:00     2         1
91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     78        1
62  2017-11-02 15:30:00     99        1
91  2017-11-02 22:45:00     34        1
47  2017-10-26 20:15:00     465       2
1   2017-10-27 00:10:00     67        2
20  2017-10-28 05:00:00     5746      2
28  2017-10-29 07:00:00     36        2
91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     786       2
58  2017-11-02 14:30:00     477       2
95  2017-11-02 23:45:00     7322      2
```

df2

```
slot
2
91
62
58
```

I need the output df3 as

```
slot              Time    Location  User
2   2017-10-27 00:30:00     54        1
91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     78        1
91  2017-11-02 22:45:00     34        1
91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     786       2
62  2017-11-02 15:30:00     99        1
58  2017-11-02 14:30:00     477       2
```

if those are csv file then we can join them

```
join File1 file2 > file3
```

But how can we do the same for the outputs in Jupyter notebook

Comment: There are several `slot=91` in `df`. Do you want to print the first one only?

Comment: Please check now @QuangHoang. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `isin`:

```
df1[df1.slot.isin(df2.slot)]
```

Output:

```
    slot               Time     Location    User
1   2   2017-10-27 00:30:00     54          1
4   91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     78          1
5   62  2017-11-02 15:30:00     99          1
6   91  2017-11-02 22:45:00     34          1
11  91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     786         2
12  58  2017-11-02 14:30:00     477         2
```